# ArcGIS Initializing License suddenly slow

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-license-manager

I have ArcGIS 10.2.2 Desktop, **License type: Advanced**, installed on a windows 7 64 bit machine.

It normally takes about 12 seconds to initialize the license, whether in ArcMap or a stand alone Python script.

Suddenly today it is taking about 50 seconds. The only thing I can think of is that I ran the `Advanced System Care Iobit registry cleaner` but I am fairly sure I have done this before since I installed 10.2.2 without problems.

I have had similar start up times before after installing an upgraded version of ArcGIS and the only way I found to cure it was to uninstall it, remove all traces from the registry and re-install but I would dearly love to be able to fix it without going through all that again.

Can anyone suggest a way to find why it is taking so long?

Comment: Have you installed additional add-ons? After I started using ArcHydro startup went from ~10 seconds to ~45-60.

Comment: No - nothing like that

Comment: Should be re-opened. Same behaviour observed on 10.4.1, with Brad's answer being the cure.

Comment: Also see Geonet [ArcMap 10 hangs at Initializing Application](https://community.esri.com/thread/15863)

Answer (score 2):

Look at the taskbar tray icons on Windows and deactivate the arcgis online Connection
[image]
[image]
tick "Never check" and test for better speed on startup.
If that helps something changed with your internet connection in the past few days.

Comment: I had same symptoms as OP with ArcMap v10.4.1. Turning systray ArcGIS Connection Properties to either of "Never Check" and "Periodic check: 60s" solved the problem. Using Connection Test showed "pass" for Proxy and Download, "undetermined" for Latency and "failed" for Route. If I sign in (ArcMap >> File >> Sign In), subsequent arcmap starts are short.